# How do I script a friend request using php/ajax/jquery?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I would appreciate help with this script:

I have this script on a page called members, what I want this script to do is when a member, let's say member A, sends a friends request by clicking the button, first the status changes to something say 'requesting...', then the script sends the request to php via the script this is what I have:

```
      <script type="text/javascript">
       var email_cont = '<?=$mem_com[email]?>';
       var cont_email = '<?=$_SESSION[email]?>';

   $('#connectButton').click(function() { 
   var counter = 0;
  $.ajax({
   url: 'requests.php?         cont_email='+cont_email+'&email_cont='+email_cont+'&counter='+counter,
         success: function( data ) {
             $('#connectButton').val(data); // set the button value to the new status.
              $('#connectButton').unbind('click');   

     }
      });
      });
   </script>
```

For clarity:

- the button has a default values called form the database.
- cont_email is the email of the member sending request
- email_status is the email receiving the request
- counter is the request count for every request sent to the members

However, my problem with script is that it only allows for one click on the request button as there are more than one posts from members on the page as it changes the status for all members even when a particular member have not sent any request. ie members A sends request to B, the status should show that request has been sent but however members C login the status of Member A/B request is still display, I want a way to make the status exclusive to each members, status should only show for a particular memeber if request has been sent else the status bears the default value.

Here is my PHP code:

```
$email_cont = $_GET['email_cont'];
$cont_email = $_GET['cont_email'];
$counter = $_GET['counter'];
$status = "Connection Sent!";

$insert = mysql_query("INSERT INTO reqst VALUES ('','$cont_email','$email_cont','$status', '$counter', NOW())");


if(!$insert) {
    //If it fails to run the SQL return an error.
    echo "Connection Failed!";
} else {
    $update = mysql_query("UPDATE upd SET request ='$status' WHERE  email ='$email_cont'");
    //If all goes well, return the status
    echo $request;
}
```

I need a way to separate the request made by member A to B from members  B to C so that the $update only update the table called upd status for  A to B while B and C or C to D maintains the default values as no request is sent yet. so that when the $request is echoed it only carry the request status of the members according to the request status, ie X if request is made, Y if no request is made, Z if request is accepted .

Answer (score 1):

Use jQuery `$.get` function to send get request to requests.php

```
$.get('requests.php' , {email_cont: "name@domain.com", cont_email: "name@domain.com", counter: "counter..", function(data){
      $('#connectButton').val(data); 
      $('#connectButton').unbind('click'); 
});
```

Comment: Thanks sabri, every thing is work fine now just that that click() event is activated once then it post multiple data to the database against the number of the element on the page, any guide on how to make the click event unique for each element and allow the event to bind to other element in case you want to send more than one connections without sending multiple datas? thanks for any help.

Comment: Well you just need to make it a function and call it on each element?
I am not sure is this what you want because I dont understand English good only codes :p [I am glad that helps to you.](http://youlinks.tv)

Comment: hello Stanley can you tick that my answer was right ?
(under the vote you have the "nick" simbole :D click it :D)